# Prime generator program SPOJ wrong answer

Tags: algorithm, go, primes

## Problem Statement

> **Input**
>
> The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line
> (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1
> <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
>
> **Output**
>
> For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n,
> one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.
>
> **Example**
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> 1 10
> 3 5
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 7
>
> 3
> 5
> ```

**My Problem**

I have tried to write this problem with `golang`, at beginning I got time limit exceed error, then I solved it with finding the biggest `n` and only generate prime once. But now I got wrong answer error. Anyone can help to to find the bug? I can't figure it out. Thanks.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var k, j, i, max_m, max_n, test_cases, kase int64
    fmt.Scanln(&test_cases)
    case_m, case_n := make([]int64, test_cases), make([]int64, test_cases)
    EratosthenesArray := make(map[int64][]bool)
    max_m = 0
    max_n = 0
    for i = 0; i < test_cases; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d %d", &case_m[i], &case_n[i])
        if case_m[i] > case_n[i] {
            case_m[i] = 0
            case_n[i] = 0
        }
        if max_m < case_m[i] {
            max_m = case_m[i]
        }
        if max_n < case_n[i] {
            max_n = case_n[i]
        }
        length := case_n[i] - case_m[i] + 1
        EratosthenesArray[i] = make([]bool, length)
    }

    if max_m <= max_n {
        upperbound := int64(math.Sqrt(float64(max_n)))
        UpperboundArray := make([]bool, upperbound+1)
        for i = 2; i <= upperbound; i++ {
            if !UpperboundArray[i] {
                for k = i * i; k <= upperbound; k += i {
                    UpperboundArray[k] = true
                }
                for kase = 0; kase < test_cases; kase++ {
                    start := (case_m[kase] - i*i) / i

                    if case_m[kase]-i*i < 0 {
                        start = i
                    }
                    for k = start * i; k <= case_n[kase]; k += i {
                        if k >= case_m[kase] && k <= case_n[kase] {
                            EratosthenesArray[kase][k-case_m[kase]] = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for i = 0; i < test_cases; i++ {
        k = 0
        for j = 0; j < case_n[i]-case_m[i]; j++ {
            if !EratosthenesArray[i][j] {
                ret := case_m[i] + j
                if ret > 1 {
                    fmt.Println(ret)
                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried running it standalone, say on ideone.com, with your own input, and checking the answers?

Comment: Can you explain more about ur approach?

Comment: @WillNess sure I did, I tested different data range, such as primes from 1 to 100, -100 to -1, 100 to 5000, 10000 to 110000 etc, all answers are correct.

Comment: @PhamTrung according to the problem, we need print out prime numbers in a given range, in order to reduce the time consumption and memory consumption, I use a modified [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm. Firstly, find the `max_n` and `max_m`, so we can use it to generate a Eratosthenes array range from 1 to `sort(max_n)`, then we can inferring the non-prime number to the requested range.

Comment: Running your code with the provided example input does *not* produce the required output and should clearly show you at least one problem (the 3 5 test case gives only 3 with your code).

Comment: @DaveC ohh... I located the problem... thanks! stupid me!

Comment: @PhamTrung re your answer, there are so few core primes below the square root that  it won't matter if you find them with trial division instead of the sive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the comments, the output for each prime number range is always have one line short, so here is the ACCEPTED solution

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var k, j, i, max_m, max_n, test_cases, kase int64
    fmt.Scanln(&test_cases)
    case_m, case_n := make([]int64, test_cases), make([]int64, test_cases)
    EratosthenesArray := make(map[int64][]bool)
    max_m = 0
    max_n = 0
    for i = 0; i < test_cases; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d %d", &case_m[i], &case_n[i])
        if case_m[i] > case_n[i] {
            case_m[i] = 0
            case_n[i] = 0
        }
        if max_m < case_m[i] {
            max_m = case_m[i]
        }
        if max_n < case_n[i] {
            max_n = case_n[i]
        }
        length := case_n[i] - case_m[i] + 1
        EratosthenesArray[i] = make([]bool, length)
    }

    if max_m <= max_n {
        upperbound := int64(math.Sqrt(float64(max_n)))
        UpperboundArray := make([]bool, upperbound+1)
        for i = 2; i <= upperbound; i++ {
            if !UpperboundArray[i] {
                for k = i * i; k <= upperbound; k += i {
                    UpperboundArray[k] = true
                }
                for kase = 0; kase < test_cases; kase++ {
                    start := (case_m[kase] - i*i) / i

                    if case_m[kase]-i*i < 0 {
                        start = i
                    }
                    for k = start * i; k <= case_n[kase]; k += i {
                        if k >= case_m[kase] && k <= case_n[kase] {
                            EratosthenesArray[kase][k-case_m[kase]] = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for i = 0; i < test_cases; i++ {
        k = 0
        for j = 0; j <= case_n[i]-case_m[i]; j++ {
            if !EratosthenesArray[i][j] {
                ret := case_m[i] + j
                if ret > 1 {
                    fmt.Println(ret)
                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Note that I only changed one line from `for j = 0; j < case_n[i]-case_m[i]; j++ {` to `for j = 0; j <= case_n[i]-case_m[i]; j++ {`

And the execution time is about 1.08s, memory is about 772M (but seems the initial memory for golang in spoj is 771M, so it might be about 1M memory usage)